# CSS cascading order - author vs user

Tags: css

In ascending order of precedence:

1. user agent declarations
2. user normal declarations
3. author normal declarations
4. author important declarations
5. user important declarations

CSS spec defines **author** and **user** as:

> **Author**. The author specifies style sheets for a source document according to the conventions of the document language. For instance,
>   in HTML, style sheets may be included in the document or linked
>   externally.
>
> **User**: The user may be able to specify style information for a particular document. For example, the user may specify a file that
>   contains a style sheet or the user agent may provide an interface that
>   generates a user style sheet (or behaves as if it did).

.. but its still not clear to me if I, the developer of the website/app, is the **user** or the **author**? Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: If you are the `developer`, you are the `author`.

Comment: Ah thanks, its indeed a duplicate and now I know I'm the author, but still unsure what is a user stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Author**

The developer of the original CSS code for that application. Let's say the Front-end developer of StackOverflow website is the Author here.

> Any changes made on Author code will effect the application style for
>   everyone.

**User**

You want to have custom style for the pages that you view. **Eg:** If you need to change the background color of Stackoverflow website, you can use [**Stylish**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) extension to append your custom style rules. Now you are the user here.

You can filter the user styles in the [**Style Side Panel**](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel) which shows the system applied styles as well as user defined custom CSS.

> Any changes made on this code will affect only your browser.

Comment: or changes from inspector (Firebug, Chrome Devtools etc..) for that matter, right? So any changes from the user's end.

Comment: Yes, changes from Firebug/Chrome DevTools as well because you are using custom styles.