# User agent overrides Author css color declaration for <a> tag for some reason

Tags: css, google-chrome, user-agent, textcolor, cascading

Maybe this will be a stupid question but why doesn't css **color** attribute work with either ***body*** or ***div*** selectors?
I was sure and I still believe it should work. But it Doesn't

It works perfectly [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_bg) on w3schools.com
but it doesn't work either on my local server or on codepen.io

It's obvious to me that in the example below "Normal author declarations"

```
body{color: red;} div{color: red;}
```

are overridden. But why?

I started my investigation from reading the documentation and found something meaningful in [14.4.2 Inheritance and cascading](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.4.2) section

> The cascading mechanism is used when a number of style rules all apply
> directly to an element. ...  If no rule can be found, the next step
> depends on whether the style property can be inherited or not.

SO? The reason why the declarations in my example don't work can arise from “**The cascading mechanism is used...**” or from “**style property can be inherited**”.

Since there is nothing to inherit ( I hope), I think the reason lays somewhere in how “The cascading mechanism is used…”

So I referred to the documentation explaining “how does css cascade” work. And  found this `https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/`

There we can learn that the property value that hits other properties and determines the final visual style of an element we see on our screens is called “**computed value**”.

So to answer “why are Author declarations overridden” I had to find out the “computed value” of “**color**” property for the anchor element.

And “Computed” tab in Chrome DevTools helped me. I inspected the  element and discovered that the “computed value” was

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Check out [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/surlq.png) please

That was very interesting to see "**user agent stylesheet**" reference because what the documentation tells us is that any “Author declarations” override any “User agent declarations” unless the latter are !**Important** ones.

I also red some other discussions on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466404/chrome-user-agent-stylesheet-overwriting-my-site-style) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet) on "Why User agent declarations override Author declarations" questions

The only reason I see is that there is an **!Important user agent** declaration that overrides **Normal Author** declarations

```
body{color: red;} div{color: red;}
```

for

```
<a>
```

html tag.

Anybody please help me to prove or disapprove the idea of the existence of any *!Important user agent* declaration that overrides my *Normal author* declarations in this example.

```css
body{
color: red;
}

div{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="link">
      <a href="#" class="url">This text should be Red. But it is blue.</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The predefined styles for the `a` tag are [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) than styles inherited from the `body` tag.

You can change the color of text in the `a` tag by targeting it directly.

```css
body {
  color: green;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Other text in the <code>body</code> is green.</p>
  <a href="#">This text is red.</a>
</body>
```

The predefined element styles vary by browser which is why some developers opt to use a [normalizing](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) style sheet. It accounts for differences between browser defaults so your site appears consistently for all users.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the reply, but I don't think so because as soon as I know according to the CSS Importance priority "The predefined styles...."  are "Default browser declarations" ones while <body> selector is an "Author declaration".
And as "Author declarations" are more important they should override "Default browser declarations". Don't they?

and they work here for some reason https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_bg

Comment: with the reference to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/32001998/14882824

Comment: Your `body` style will override the default `body` style, yes. The default `a` style is more specific than even your `body` style because it targets the element directly instead of being inherited.

Comment: Thank you @Dakota Methvin. Now I do see the difference but since it is still not clear for me why "Normal author declarations" are overridden I conducted a little investigation. I'll post in here soon.